# How To Access Data Of Dynamicly Created Child Component From Parent Component

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have a parent component "Builder" that has a plus button. When I click on this button, a method "newHighSchoolComponent" is called, thanks to which I create a new child component and attach it to a `<div>` inside the parent component.

```
    // Parent Component "Builder"
    <div>
         <br>
         <div id="high_school_data_holder" v-for="i in 1">
    
         </div>
         <button class="add" @click="newHighSchoolComponent">
                 <img src="/img/plus.svg" style="width: 1.2rem;">
         </button>
    </div>


    
    // Parent Vue
export default {
    import HighSchoolComponent from "./HighSchoolComponent";
    .
    .
    .
    const HighSchool = {
        props: ['id', 'name', 'town', 'fos', 'start', 'end'],
        template: '<resume-high-school-component data-id="high_school_data" ref="high_school_data" :id="id" :name="name" :town="town" :fos="fos" :start="start" :end="end"></resume-high-school-component>',
    };
    .
    .
    .
    methods: {
        newHighSchoolComponent() {
             const HighSchoolCtor = Vue.extend(HighSchool);
             const vm = new HighSchoolCtor({});
             vm.$mount();
             $("#high_school_data_holder").append(vm.$el);
        },
    }
}



// Child Component "HighSchool"
<div class="">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label :for="'school_name_'+school_id">School name</label>
       <input v-model="school_name" class="form-control hs_input" type="text" :id="'school_name_'+school_id" name="school_name">
   </div>
   .
   .
   .
   more input data
   .
   .
   .
</div>



// Child Vue
export default {
        props: ['id', 'name', 'town', 'fos', 'start', 'end'],
        data() {
            return {
                school_id: this.id,
                school_name: this.name,
                .
                .
                .
                more data
            }
        },
    }
```

This works fine. I click on the button, new child component is created and attached to the `<div>`. I may create as many of these child components as I want.

But the thing is that the parent component does not see the $refs of the created child components so I can't get the data by using `this.$refs.high_school_data.$data`. Guess because it was created like this?

Right now I get the child component data by looping through `.hs_input` class like this in the parent component.

```
var inputs = $(".hs_input");
var high_school_data = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
          high_school_data.push($(inputs[i]).val());
}
```

The more child components I create the longer this `high_school_data` array is and it is very ugly and uncomfortable to work with.

Is there a better way how to get data from multiple dynamicly created components?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to _store_ or _access_ the child component data in the parent, but have it editable in the children, is that correct?

Comment: @James By clicking on a button in Parent I am able to dynamicly create Child components inside the Parent and attach it there. Inside the Child are inputs which I can fill out. Now, from the parent, I need to access these filled out inputs. If I did not create this Child dynamicly, I could do this by using the $refs. But now I can't so I am trying to find a way to access the Child data.

Comment: You need to think about this differently. The parent needs to be the source of truth. It will hold an array of child objects that hold the fields. When one of the child inputs changes state, it must **emit** up to the parent so that the parent can change the state. The child component will then rerender to reflect this. This is done using bound inputs (its been a while since I've used Vue, but you are going to bind to the :value on each child input and use the value that it receives via a prop).

Comment: @James What exactly do you mean by "parent will hold an array of child objects" ? I am able to bind data via props right now, I just can't get them back to parent.

Comment: You're doing it jQuery style in Vue, that's where your problems come from :)  Vue style would be to add the new child components in the parent template. ````<div id="high_school_data_holder" v-for="(school) in highSchools"> <HighSchoolCtor /> </div>````

Comment: You bind the values down; that is correct. But you also need to listen to emitted events from the child to update the state. You will therefore need to bind the child inputs so that they emit when the value changes.

Comment: Thank You all ! I solved my problem with your help.